# 3ds Max -> three.js opacity map

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax

I'm adding an opacity map with an alpha channel to my standard material in my .max file. The opacity map does not work/show after translated into three.js. Properties like texture, color, roughness etc are visible and working. The only problems seems to be with this alpha channel.

Should I follow any extraordinary steps for bringing the opacity map into three.js?

Comment: Which loader are you using? have you tried using different formats?

Comment: We have to use the .max format in our workflow. I've tried fbx and obj as well. We're translating the file into SVF (Autodesk Forge Viewer) which is based on three.js

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know SVF doesn't support transparency map.  The best you can do to have some transparency is to set the transparency color for physical material or the opacity value for standard material inside of 3ds Max.  However, this will apply transparency on your entire material.